# Implementing selection sort on a singly linked list

Tags: c++, stl, selection-sort, forward-list

Heya I'm trying to implement selection sort algorithm on a singly linked list , I'm aware that there is some problem in the code but although My linked list includes the numbers 7 1 2 6  the output after running is  7777 . Any help would be appreciated.

```
template<class Type>
void UnOrderedLinkedList<Type>::selectionSort()
{
nodeType<Type>* loc;
nodeType<Type>* minIndex;
nodeType<Type>* temp;
temp = first;
if(temp == NULL)
    cerr<<"Cannot sort an empty list."<<endl;
else
    if(temp->link == NULL)
    cerr<<"List has only one item so it is already sorted."<<endl;
else

while(temp != NULL)
{
    minIndex = minLocation(temp, last);
    swap(temp, minIndex);
    temp = temp->link;
}
}


template<class Type>
nodeType<Type>* UnOrderedLinkedList<Type>::minLocation(nodeType<Type>* first, nodeType<Type>* last)

nodeType<Type>* minIndex;
nodeType<Type>* other;

minIndex = first;
other = minIndex->link;

while(other != NULL)
{
    if(minIndex->info > other->info)
    {
        minIndex = other;
        other = other->link;
    }

    else
    {
        other = other->link;
    }

}
    return minIndex;
}
```

Then to swap:

```
template<class Type>
void UnOrderedLinkedList<Type>::swap(nodeType<Type>* first, nodeType<Type>* second)
{
     nodeType<Type>* temp;
     temp->info = first->info;
     first->info = second->info;
     second->info = temp->info;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your `swap` function:

```
 nodeType<Type>* temp;
 temp->info = first->info;
```

That is a clear case of *undefined behavior*! You declare a local variable, a pointer, without initialization. Then you directly uses the uninitialized variable, leading to said UB. Since you use pointers, you should actually be happy that the program didn't crash.

Here you don't need a pointer or a node as you don't actually swap nodes. All you need is an instance of what `info` is, and use that:

```
SomeType temp;
temp = first->info;
first->info = second->info;
second->info = temp;
```

Comment: Joachim Thank you so much  my code perfectly works now! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @JoachimPileborg works of course, but note that you don't need to write a member function `sort` of your own singly linked list in order to do selection sort.

The reason is that a [**generic version**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24650626/819272) of `selection_sort` (with `O(N^2)` complexity) is already compatible any singly linked list that exposes **forward iterators**, such as the one from the Standard Library, `std::forward_list`:

```
#include <algorithm>    // min_element, iter_swap, is_sorted
#include <cassert>      // assert
#include <forward_list> // forward_list
#include <functional>   // less
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <ios>          // boolalpha
#include <iterator>     // distance, next

template<class FwdIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
void selection_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
{
    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
        auto const selection = std::min_element(it, last, cmp);
        std::iter_swap(selection, it); 
        assert(std::is_sorted(first, std::next(it), cmp));
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto fl = std::forward_list<int> { 2, 4, 1, 0, -1, 8, 2 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_sorted(fl.begin(), fl.end()) << '\n';
    for (auto const& e : fl) std::cout << e << ", "; std::cout << '\n';
    selection_sort(fl.begin(), fl.end());
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_sorted(fl.begin(), fl.end()) << '\n';
    for (auto const& e : fl) std::cout << e << ", "; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5791ebb702f805d2)

Note that `std::forward_list` also implements its own member function `sort`. This version -which does an `O(N log N)` merge sort- can not be implemented based on the public interface alone (actually you can, but with `O(N)` extra storage instead of the `O(1)` storage that `forward_list` guarantees).